# Can't get Angular PWA set up correctly

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've been following Angular's documentation to set up my project as a progressive web app, but when I go to run it on my local server, I get an error that says `"GET /" Error (404): "Not found"`. Does anybody know what might be causing this issue, and how I could fix this?

The steps I'm taking are:

1. Running the command `ng add @angular/pwa --project disc-golf-project`
2. Running `ng build --prod`.
3. Running `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/disc-golf-project`
4. Going to http://localhost:8080/  (This is where I get a 404 error)

I have a feeling it might be my routing since I redirect to /home. Here is the my app-routing.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { PlayerSelectionComponent } from "./player-selection/player-selection.component";
import { HighscoresComponent } from "./highscores/highscores.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";
import { GameComponent } from "./game/game.component";
import { ResultsComponent } from "./results/results.component";
import { WeatherComponent } from './weather/weather.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "highscores", component: HighscoresComponent },
  { path: "player-selection", component: PlayerSelectionComponent },
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
  { path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "home" },
  { path: "game", component: GameComponent },
  { path: "results", component: ResultsComponent },
  { path: "weather", component: WeatherComponent },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Just let me know if you need more info, and I will post it.

Comment: Have you tried running it with the [angular-http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server)? since its a SPA, the routing mechanism might confuse the http-server

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the potential routing issues (Just revert to normal on that one and see if you can hit the site), setting up angular as a PWA has few steps:

Having run ng add @angular/pwa this should already be working to the point you have the PWS setup - potentailly you have published with an empty site or your caching something. F12 -> Application tab -> Service workers.

Can you see anything listed?
And under Cache Storage clear everything too to be sure. Initial use of PWS's often leads to unexpected caching that leads to these issues.#

Should you find nothing, check your work against googles PWS course. First 2/3 little chapters should cover everything your up to:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/dev-pwa-training/

Comment: I run into issues in paragraph two of your response. I ran the ng add @angular/pwa command, but then when I build it and go to my local http-server, I get a 404 instantly. I went to the application tab in developer tools to check what you were asking, and there was nothing there. No service worker, no cache, nothing.

Comment: Do you have your project in github? I can pull it and try